# while condition in shell script with -h in condition checking

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to understand the `karaf.sh` in `jboss-fuse` `esb` shell scripts. I am unable to understand  below line.

```
while [ -h "${dst}" ] ;
```

Can anyone let me know **what -h** will do in the condition checking statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Bash conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) section from the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) you can find the following:

> -h file 
>   True if file exists and is a symbolic link.